# If statement with strings not working

Tags: c++

```
void listgames()
{
    using namespace std;
    newLine();
    cout << " [Albert] Would you like to open [League] [Osu] [Pandora] [Google] [Youtube] ?" << endl << endl;
    string game;
    cout << " ";
    cin >> game;
    for (int l = 0; game[l] != '\0'; l++)
    {
        game[l] = toupper(game[0]);
    }
    if (game.compare("LEAGUE"))
    {
        ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\League\\league.lnk", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
        std::cout << " [Albert] [Reminder] Don't forget to focus and try your best, but most importantly have fun!" << std::endl;
    }
    if (game.compare("OSU"))
    {
        ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\osu!", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
        std::cout << " [Albert] Good luck!!";
    }
```

Not working.... =/

I'm trying to get input on which game they want to start and check if they chose that certain game...

But no matter what input I enter, both games will open.

Comment: `game[l] = toupper(game[0])` Did you mean to fill the string with copies of its first character? You are turning, say, `"Google"` into `"GGGGGG"`

Comment: Oh I thought that was how you made the string capitalilzed... How can I make it capitilized??

Comment: Also, you are using `string::compare` incorrectly. It returns 0 when two strings are equal, non-zero otherwise

Comment: Would that even explain why they both open up though? sorry about this btw im new to coding...

Comment: ohh okay, thanks, but how would I make it all capital??

Answer (score 1):

`compare` will return 0 if two strings are equal. If you want to equality to evaluate to true you should either do

```
!string.compare(other)
```

or

```
string.compare(other) == 0
```

There is another issue with this. In your for loop you are setting each character in the string to the upper-cased version of your first character.

As James said, if you want to upper case the string you need to change

```
game[l] = toupper(game[0]);
```

to

```
game[l] = toupper(game[l]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`compare` will return `0` if both strings are equal. Your strings can never be equal (explained further down), so it always returns non-zero. Anything non-zero is converted to the boolean `true`, and so both `if` conditionals always run.

Use `==`.

```
if (game == "LEAGUE")
```

As mentioned in the comments, `game[l] = toupper(game[0])` is setting every character in the string to the uppercase version of the first letter. Replace the `0` with `l`:

```
`game[l] = toupper(game[l])`
```

Or if you want to use the library, replace the loop with:

```
std::for_each(game.begin(), game.end(), [](char& c){ c = std::toupper(c); } );
```